# Websocket - Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 404

Tags: javascript, php, apache, websocket

I am using websocket in my app and everything worked fine when i was using localhost. The problem starts when i changed localhost to my server ip address then i got this error:
**Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 404**

This is my httpd.conf

```
...

Listen 25.48.63.220:80
Listen 25.48.63.220:8081

...

ServerName 25.48.63.220:80

...
```

I think that i am able to connect with my server because when i typed wrong ip address i don't  get this error.

What else i have to to change ?

Answer (score 0):

404 means Not Found. Probably you are connecting to the wrong place, or you didn't map the port from your public IP address to your local IP address.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem. If you are using composer to download Ratchet you need to change constructor in /vendor/cboden/ratchet/src/Ratchet/App.php.

```
Default __construct should look like this:
 public function __construct($httpHost = 'localhost', $port = 80, $address = 'localhost', LoopInterface $loop = null) {
```

So you only need to change httpHost, port and address. It works for me :)

Comment: Please don't change the Ratcet\App constructor that you get through Composer. Just pass your values to the Ratchet\App constructor: $ws = new Ratchet\App($httpHost='localhost', $port=80, $address='localhost', $loop=null);